# Принудительное обновление виджета android

Tags: android, виджет

Нужно по нажатию на кнопку в виджете, обновить его, как это можно сделать ?

Comment: А в чем конкретно  проблема? просто обновите через manager

Comment: А как именно это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent updateIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetPrvdr.class);
            updateIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            updateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[] { id });

            pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, updateIntent, 0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tvPressUpdate, pIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
manager.updateAppWidget(currentWidget, view);
```